# The history of appearance of Ctrl-Enter

Tags: user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts, history, usability

Is there anybody who knows the history of appearance of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> hotkey which means "Send"? It is pretty "classic" now. I remember that for the first time I've met that hotkey in ICQ 99, but now almost every IM have such hotkey and many popular social networking sites. Some time ago I was surprised that in the "Commit" dialog of eclipse IDE that hotkey also available with the same meaning.

Comment: I've used some programs where Enter was submit and Ctrl-Enter was newline. Which makes it easier to prematurely submit.

Comment: And in most cases it was possible to change the meaning of these to vice-versa!

Comment: @Jimmy Skype (probably other IM`s), anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> doesn't mean "Send". It means, "double-click", or "do the default".

Comment: Yeah, after playing with that hotkey in several dialogs of different applications I've found that you're probably right.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it's impossible to answer something like this for certain, but I'll offer myself as a candidate for creating this standard.

In the summer of 1992, I was a junior programmer at America Online (AOL), working on what was to be version 1.0 of the Windows AOL client software.  Part of my duties included refining many of the UI forms, including E-mail composition and Instant Message composition.  Like many techies of that era, I was a keyboard jockey... using a mouse just slowed me down.  I wanted a way to send messages quickly.  Some of my colleagues suggested that I could just hit TAB until input focus was on the "Send" button, then hit the spacebar to activate the button.  That was true enough, but for me the problem was that every composition form was structured differently... maybe the E-mail form needed <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd>  <kbd>Space</kbd> , while the IM form needed <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd>  <kbd>Space</kbd> .  Sometimes it even varied for new messages vs. replies.  Yuck.

One day I became tired of the inconsistency, and decided to add a consistent keyboard shortcut for "Send" to all composition forms.  My first choice was actually the Enter key on the numeric keypad.  Seemed easy enough, but I soon realized that many people used the numeric keypad to move the input cursor, and would sometimes mistakenly hit the Enter key, prematurely sending their message.  Not good.  Next beta release, I changed all those shortcuts to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd>, with the idea that it was virtually impossible to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> by mistake, but quite easy to hit that key combo with one hand if that was your intention.

There were no reported complaints about that shortcut, nor did I explicitly document it anywhere.  However, before long, various "guides to America Online" had published the shortcut, and it remains to this day, AFAIK.  At the time I selected that shortcut, I was not aware of any other software that used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> to mean "Send".

Over the following few years, the Windows America Online client was arguably the single most popular way to send online messages, and I know the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> shortcut became very popular amongst power users.  This solidly predated Windows 95 and its related apps.  Was this the true genesis of the shortcut?  I don't know for sure, but I like to think so.  :)

Answer (score 1):

In email clients <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> was the shorcut for *finish-editing-and-send*. I remember using it in [Microsoft Internet Mail and News](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Internet_Mail_and_News) back in Win95 days. Probably  Mirabilis copied it for ICQ and others copied from ICQ.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first, and probably still most obvious, use for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> was to insert a new line, in a text box where usually you don't need more than one line, and thus the simple Enter is used to confirm the entry.

In applications where you do need to enter many lines, such as e-mail clients, it comes natural to do the opposite, that is assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> to the function normally associated with simple Enter (usually confirm the entry, which can be regarded as send the message in an e-mail client).

I don't have historic references, so I can't say for sure, but I saw <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> used for line inserting a lot earlier than seeing it used to send a message.



The thing is that it's usually an hidden use, in that you rarely need it and is rarely documented, but if you try you'll see a lot of apparently single-line text boxes accepting a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> to insert a new line, and that often turns out as a big time-saver and a major increase in the usefulness of the functionality.



The shortcut is probably harmed significantly by the use of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> in Excel to enter new lines, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> left for a more obscure functionality (and probably just as a side-effect for confirming the entry without moving to another cell). It's likely that more people know about this than the (to my knowledge) much more widely used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd>.
Of course it's also possible that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> came first, I'm not really a software historian